# Wordpress Multi-Site - Persistent Logins Accross All Sites?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

As the title states, is there an efficient way for all sites on a wp multi-site network to recognize logins on the entire network while still limiting user privileges to their own site?

I've been searching for a fairly efficient way to do this but cannot find one that wordpress supports.